# styling difference between IE11 and chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I've this simple button with a `+` or a `-` as content

```
<button></button>

button::before {
    content: '-';
}
button.active::before {
    content: '+';
}
```

In all browsers I have installed on my Mac (Chrome,safari and Firefox) this button is styled correct, but check it out in IE11 (or even FireFox on Windows 8.1 its not perfect) the styling is bad

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/a9bh2jgs/7/)

Can someone explain to me what is wrong in my css, or maybe (most likely) what is wrong with IE11. Is there a fix, or should I change the css and don't use `position: absolute` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add `left` and `top` properties on the absolutely positioned element. Add them and IE will behave as expected.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/a9bh2jgs/9/)

Comment: Thanks. Chrome defaults!